# Handling Sequences in Coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to use a Sequence (e.g. [FileTreeWalk](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/-file-tree-walk/index.html) returned from File.walk) inside a coroutine, but my implementation keeps blocking the ui thread.

Is there a good way to handle Sequences and mapping the items within coroutines?

Here is a snipped of my code:

```
override fun onResume() {
  super.onResume()
  launch {
    apkFiles = searchMyFiles(rootDir).await()
    showMyFiles()
  }
}

private fun searchMyFiles(dir: File): Deferred<MutableList<MyFile>> {
  return async {
    dir.walk().filter { !it.isDirectory }
      .filter { it.extension.equals(MY_EXTENSION, true) }
      .map { MyFile(it, context) }.filter { it.valid 
    }.sorted().toMutableList()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although there's no evidence from your code, I'll make a guess that your default dispatcher, set in the `CoroutineScope` you implicitly use, is `Dispatchers.Main` (the UI thread). You keep using the same dispatcher for your background job instead of `Dispatchers.IO`.

A second point is that you use `async-await` for no purpose, you should use `withContext` instead and declare your function as `suspend fun`.

Given the above, your code should be

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    launch {
        apkFiles = searchMyFiles(rootDir)
        showMyFiles()
    }
}

private suspend fun searchMyFiles(dir: File) : MutableList<MyFile> = 
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        dir.walk()
           .filter { !it.isDirectory }
           .filter { it.extension.equals(MY_EXTENSION, true) }
           .map { MyFile(it, context) }
           .filter { it.valid }
           .sorted()
           .toMutableList()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Looks like I was using the scopes wrong. My initial thought was the action inside the map operator needed to run in separate coroutine.

Comment: Lazy sequence processing actually makes no difference because `toMutableList` is a terminal operation and eagerly collects everything to a list.